# Weird deformation when scaling mirrored cylinder

Tags: mesh, transforms, mirror, mirror-modifier

I'm modelling a character, so far so good. The only problem is in the body part, which is just supposed to be a cloth robe or alike. The whole thing is mirrored so it gets symmetrical, but when trying to scale, things get clunky:

[image]

It should be like this, but this is with the effect already applied:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a *Mirror* modifier to get a full circle, so your selection is just a half circle, not a circle, your *Transform Pivot Point* is probably set to *Median Point*, which will scale the half circle, not a full circle. In order to get a good result, put the 3D cursor at the center of your circle, choose *3D Cursor* as *Transform Pivot Point* and scale:

[image]